# 'Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")}

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am trying to launch cassandra container using docker-compose, but stay recieving this error message:

```
cassandra-server_1  | Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', 
{'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Notice that I get it working well when I use directly this command line:

```
$ docker run -d --name=c1 bitnami/cassandra:3.11.6
```

And then I ssh the container, and using `CQLSH` command normaly.

I know it is related to the networking, and I tried everything I was able to without success !

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  cassandra-server:
    image: 'bitnami/cassandra:3.11.6'
    network_mode: host
    expose:
      - 7000
      - 7001
      - 7199
      - 9042
      - 9142
    ports:
      - '9042:9042'
    command: bash -c 'cqlsh'
```

I am using the `network mode: Host` after switching from `bridge mode`.

Here is my other configuration with `bridge mode`:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24

services:
  cassandra-server:
    image: 'bitnami/cassandra:3.11.6'
    networks:
      - aapp-tier
    expose:
      - 7000
      - 7001
      - 7199
      - 9042
      - 9142
    ports:
      - '9042:9042'
    command: bash -c 'cqlsh'
```

Unfortunately I get the same error message for both configurations.

#### UPDATE:

When I launch this command:

```
docker run -it --rm --network app-tier bitnami/cassandra:latest cqlsh --username cassandra --password cassandra
```

I recieve this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2443, in <module>
    main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
  File "/opt/bitnami/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2421, in main
    encoding=options.encoding)
  File "/opt/bitnami/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py", line 485, in __init__
    load_balancing_policy=WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy([self.hostname]),
  File "/opt/bitnami/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.11.0-bb96859b.zip/cassandra-driver-3.11.0-bb96859b/cassandra/policies.py", line
417, in __init__
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

#### Info versions

**Version**

- Output of `docker version`:

```
Client:
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.7
 Git commit:        74b1e89e8a
 Built:             Wed Jul 31 15:18:18 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea838
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:28:45 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

- Output of `docker info`:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 2
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 7
 Server Version: 19.03.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc version: 3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.14.154-boot2docker
 Operating System: Boot2Docker 19.03.5 (TCL 10.1)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 1
 Total Memory: 989.5MiB
 Name: default
 ID: VOY2:F3HL:T3RR:5RYH:RTGG:6HOS:EPZ3:WIYL:J22K:UVAD:ZHEQ:TDRW
 Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Username: progwebinfo
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
  provider=virtualbox
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

- Output of `docker-compose version` (if applicable):

```
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
docker-py version: 3.7.3
CPython version: 3.6.8
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018
```

**Additional environment details (AWS, VirtualBox, Docker for MAC, physical, etc.):**

I am on Windows 7 24bit
Using Docker Toolbox

Comment: On Docker Toolbox you can't generally use `localhost`; you need the `docker-machine ip` address, usually 192.168.99.100.  Try deleting all of the `network_mode:`, `ipam:`, and `expose:` options (but do leave `ports:`) and using this IP address from the host.

Comment: I am using `docker-machine ip default`, but I need to use it from other service and from inside docker ... unfortunately I get the same errors.

Comment: From other containers, you can use the Compose service name `cassandra-server` as a host name (assuming none of the containers involved use host networking).  The `command:` you show tries to run cqlsh instead of the Cassandra server, so also remove this line.

Comment: But the problem is that it don't work even from the same container, `docker exec -it "Container ID" bash`, and launch `CQLSH`, I recieve that error. I also updated the pôst with another error when I use another command line. Thanks again :)